# jquery window load function not doing anything on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

posting for the first time on here, just wondering what im doing wrong within this little jquery script I wrote for a external html file containing my menu element. It works on resize just not load. I've tried a standalone $(window).load(); event as well and nothing seems to work. I'm new to jQuery and just know the do's and donts yet!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var vwidth = $(window).width();
  var vheight = $(window).height();
  var menu = $('#menu_container');

  $( window ).on('load resize', function() {
    if (vwidth >= 1000) {
      menu.css('zoom', '1');
    } else {
      menu.css('zoom', '0.8');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: share your html code which elemet to call a onload function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here. One already explained by @Mr. Polywhirl.
The other one is the fact that the DOM ready event will excute AFTER the `window.load` event. That means that by the time `jQuery(document).ready` executes `$(window).load` has already happened, so the event registration for `window.load` it's a bit late. Try this instead...

```
//this is essentially the same as jQuery(document).ready
$(function(){
    toggleZoom();

    $(window).on("resize", function(){
        toggleZoom();
    });
});



function toggleZoom(){    
  var vwidth = $(window).width();
  //this isn't needed in this snippet
  //var vheight = $(window).height();
  var menu = $('#menu_container');


    if (vwidth >= 1000) {
      menu.css('zoom', '1');
    } else {
      menu.css('zoom', '0.8');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, that helped a ton, I was able to get the window load function working and thanks for reminding me to make something like this a function. Also thanks to @Mr. Polywhirl for the little tip, I guess that's why there a problem to learning programming online just by reading forums and documentation.

Comment: @NelsonMcCullough no worries mate, glad I helped

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
```

Remove the dollar sign (`$`) from the function above. You are redefining the global as a function argument for the scope of the `jQuery.ready` function.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
```

---

#### Edit

If that does not work, try some of these basic calls and see what the console prints out.

When I click the <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button, I get the following output:

```
Document ready()
Window resize()
Window load()
Window load() x2
Window resize()
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Document ready()");
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
  console.log("Window load()");
});

// or

$(window).on({
  load : function() {
    console.log("Window load() x2");
  },
  resize : function() {
    console.log("Window resize()");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage for jQuery `ready()` function is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   //The code you want to execute.
});
```

For more info look at:

https://api.jquery.com/ready/